# Como puedo agregar un objeto dentro de otro?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

Buen día.

Tengo un view en asp.net mvc, donde al momento de accesar, en la consola me muestra un json con los datos que tengo visualizables en el view.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo que quiero hacer es que así como se muestra el json uno, está dentro del mismo json principal, quiero otro para poder acceder a más información mediante jquery dentro de AJAX donde obtengo los datos que quiero.

```
function Atenciones() {

        console.log('atenciones');
        showSpinner();

        var URL = '@Url.Action("AtencionesPorSolicitudId", "SolicitudAtenciones")' + '/' + '@ViewBag.SolicitudId';
        console.log('url ' + URL);
        var card = "";
        $.getJSON({
            url: URL,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                //var d = (JSON.parse(data));
                console.log(data);

                $.each(data.atenciones, function (i, o) {

                    card += "<div class='row'>";
                    card += "<div class='col-md-6'>";
                    card += "<div class='card card-default'>";

                    //CARD HEADER
                    card += "<div class='card-header with-border'>";
                    card += "<h3 class='card-title'>Atención</h3><div class='float-right' >Fecha: <span >" + $.format.toBrowserTimeZone(new Date(o.Fecha.substr(o.Fecha.indexOf("(") + 1, 13) - 0)) + "</span></div><br/>";
                    card += "</div>";

                    card += "<div class='card-body'>";

                    //AGENTE
                    if (o.Agente == null) {
                        card += "<div><label>Agente</label><br>N/A</div><br>";
                    } else {
                        card += "<div><label>Agente</label><br>" + o.Agente + "</div><br>";
                    }
                    /////
```

Esta función obtiene el json de la función del controlador y por medio de jquery obtengo el objeto manipulable.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> AtencionesPorSolicitudId(int id)
        {
            var atenciones = await db.SolicitudAtenciones.Where(x => x.SolicitudId == id & x.Activo == true).OrderByDescending(x => x.Fecha).ThenByDescending(x => x.SolicitudAtencionId).ToListAsync();
            return Json(new { atenciones }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Esta función me devuelve el json mediante un parámetro id de dicha "solicitud" a seleccionar anteriormente.

Comment: `Y lo que quiero es que así como el json está dentro del mismo json principal, quiero otro para poder acceder a más información.` Yo lo entendí perfecto, pero deberías explicarlo de otra manera para que la gente que no tiene poderes telepáticos también pueda entender.

Comment: Una pregunta bien definida, es una pregunta medio resuelta. Lectura altamente recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Comment: Ya pude editarla un poco "mejor"